# What are the differences between OpenID and myOpenID?

Tags: openid

How different are OpenID and myOpenID? Do they differ in basic functionality or in other ways?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe OpenID is a [technology standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) while myOpenID is just [one of many providers](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/).

Answer (score 3):

OpenID is the actual authentication method for logging in, and myOpenID is a free server that one can use to utilise OpenID.